# Shell script logic to choose between BuildNumber and version for jenkins deploy

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I am working on a Jenkins deploy job for which the Build stage need to have a shell script logic. The logic is I need to retrieve jars from repository based on the build number provided or version number provided. I know the curl command to retrieve those jars but the problem is I am unable to write a shell script logic to make it work. Please find the below code logic that I have written

```
    #!/bin/bash
if [ -n $Version ]; then
    echo "Version is present"
    curl http://localhost:8080/artifactoryservices/artifactory/downloadArtifact/${Version}
elif [ -n $BuildNumber ]; then
    echo "BuildNumber is Present"
    curl http://localhost:8080/artifactoryservices/artifactory/downloadArtifact/${BuildNumber}
else
    echo "No Version or Build Number found"
fi
```

The problem is no matter I give Version number or build number the if loop is getting executed and the elif is not getting executed.
Could you please let me know is there any syntax error present in the code or is there another way to write the shell code logic for this implementation?

Comment: just double the brackets and it will work, like this: `[[ -n $Version ]]`

Comment: Don't know whether this is copy&paste error, but the #! in the first line must be at the start of the line.

Comment: Can I assume, that `Version` is an environment variable? Note that `[ -n $Version ]` will produce an error, if the variable is empty. You would have to write `[ -n "$Version" ]`, or use the approach suggested by Rahul Sharma.

Comment: Yes Version is environment variable. After including '[[" brackets and quotes for $Version the code worked! Thanks!